# Is it possible to make inputs in a Mousetracker?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like a div that follows the cursor. But you should have the possibility to make inputs in the div. Unfortunately I can only get it that the div follows the cursor, but the cursor does not enter the div.

Or Something like this: 
Is it possible that the cursor is trapped in the div? Until he either breaks off or enters. If the cursor moves to the border, the div should move in the appropriate direction. (The close function is currently not present in the code, but I can solve that myself.)

```js
var MicrosoftModel=0;
var xplus=10,yplus=10;
var runnerobject;

                          
function MouseAction(mausx,mausy)
{
    
  runnerobject.left=mausx+xplus;
  runnerobject.top=mausy+yplus;
}

function MouseMove(event)
{
    
  var mausx,mausy;
  if (typeof(event)!="object")              
    return;
  if (MicrosoftModel)                     
  {
      document.getElementById("runner").style.display = "none!important";
    mausx=event.clientX;
    mausy=event.clientY;
    if (document.body.scrollLeft)
      mausx+=document.body.scrollLeft;
    if (document.body.scrollTop)
      mausy+=document.body.scrollTop;
  }
  else                                    
  {
    mausx=event.pageX;
    mausy=event.pageY;
  }
  MouseAction(mausx,mausy);
}

          
function MouseInit()
{
    document.getElementById("runner").style.display = "none!important";
  if (document.all)         
  {
    MicrosoftModel=1;
    window.onmousemove=MouseMove;
    runnerobject=document.all.runner.style;
  }
  if (!(MicrosoftModel))                  
  {
    if (typeof(document.addEventListener)=="function")
                                         
    {
      document.addEventListener("mousemove",MouseMove,true);
      runnerobject=document.getElementById("runner").style;
    }
    else
    if (document.runner)                 
    {
      window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
      window.onmousemove=MouseMove;
      runnerobject=document.runner;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body { 
  background-color: black; 
}

.cursor-catcher{ 
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.70);
  max-width: 644px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 22px 36px 22px 36px;
}

.x{
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="MouseInit();" onMouseMove="MouseMove(event);">

<div name="runner" id="runner" style="position:absolute; left:10; top:50;">
<div class="cursor-catcher">
    <h2>Newsletter</h2>
    Name: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br> 
    <br>
    <div class="x">x</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You want to stop the user being able to move the cursor outside a div on a webpage?  I would immediately blacklist your website if that was possible.

Comment: Take a look at the [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API).

Comment: No, I think you have misunderstood this. I want the div to behave like a mouse tracker and is caught in the div. You should be able to make entries in the div. If you don't want to make any input, you can simply close the mouse tracker. @Archer

Comment: Kind of a misleading title, sounds like you want to prevent the client from doing something.  What you want, is to have a div follow the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works pretty well, I think this is the idea. (no buffer needed).

I added your form (I ignored style, you can put it back)

And now, as requested, it doesn't go heigher than 100px from the top

```
<head>
<style>
#my_div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#my_div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
<script>
var my_div;
topIgnore = 100;  // (in pixel units) used for function ignoreTop

window.onload = function() {
  my_div = document.getElementById('my_div');
  var my_div_style = window.getComputedStyle(my_div);
  var width_div = parseInt(my_div_style.width, 10);  // remove 'px' from string
  var height_div = parseInt(my_div_style.height, 10);
  // make sure the property exists, else you can get a NaN
  my_div.style.left = 0;
  my_div.style.top = 0;
  // event
  window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // my_div.innerHTML = e.pageX +' - '+ (leftBorder + width_div) +' - '+ width_div;
    cursorIsInsideDiv(e);
  }
  // TO DO: feel free to make similar functions for left/right/bottom
  // removes the first 100px
  function ignoreTop(top) {
    if(top < topIgnore) {
      return topIgnore;
    }
    return top;
  }
  function cursorIsInsideDiv(e) {
    var leftBorder = parseInt(my_div.style.left, 10); // remove 'px' from string
    var topBorder  = parseInt(my_div.style.top, 10);  
    // move left 
    if( e.pageX <  leftBorder ) {
      my_div.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    }
    // move right
    else if( e.pageX >  (leftBorder + width_div)) {
      my_div.style.left = (e.pageX - width_div ) + 'px';
    }
    // move up 
    if( e.pageY <  topBorder ) {
      var top = e.pageY ;
      top = ignoreTop(top);
      my_div.style.top = top + 'px';
    }
    // move down
    else if( e.pageY >  (topBorder + height_div)) {
      my_div.style.top = (e.pageY - height_div ) + 'px';
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my_div">
  <h2>Newsletter</h2>
  Name: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
</div>
</body>
```

---

Original post:

```
<head>
  <style>
    #my_div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #my_div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #ff0000;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var my_div;
    window.onload = function() {
      my_div = document.getElementById('my_div');
      my_div_style = window.getComputedStyle(my_div);
      var width_div = parseInt(my_div_style.width, 10);  // remove 'px' from string
      var height_div = parseInt(my_div_style.height, 10);
      // event
      window.onmousemove = function(e) {
        my_div.innerHTML = e.pageX + ',' + e.pageY + '<br/>' + width_div + ',' + height_div;
        my_div.style.left = e.pageX - Math.floor(width_div/2);
        my_div.style.top  = e.pageY - Math.floor(height_div/2);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my_div"></div>
</body>
```

Works pretty well, pretty cool effect.

Of course you don't need that my_div.innerHTML line.

Any more specific features you need (there was an edit to your question, maybe I missed something) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a possibility that the mouse within the red divs can also be moved and only when the mouse pushes to the edge, moves the red div as in your example? @EmmanuelDelay

Comment: Ah, like that.  Sure.  So I'll make a buffer (for example 3 pixel from the border); any time the cursor is within that buffer, action is taken.  For example: the cursor is dragged towards bottom-left, then I keep the bottom-left of the div at cursor position instead of moving it to the middle.  Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes something like that. That with the buffer is good. In the red field a buffer. In this buffer, the mouse can move freely without the red field moving along. If the mouse leaves this buffer, the red field should move as in your example.

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can implement this idea with the buffer?

Comment: The div should stop 100px before the top. At which point of the code, I can install that? @Emmanuel Delay –